# Python: My MacBook suddenly fails to perform an cv2.imshow

Tags: python, opencv

My code worked well until morning, but suddenly cv.imshow doesn't work. (no error!!)

I didn't change the code.

I just updated my Macbook to big sur 11.1 and deleted the Paralls and the Office.

this is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
cv2.imshow("test", img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using opencv 4.4.0

please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to a MacBook update.

I had the same problem as you.

try this:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Comment: Why have you recommended headless?  The OP just needs to reinstall the same package currently installed on their system.  Headless would be for systems where you can't physically access them (i.e. cloud), so any GUI elements are unnecessary.  You don't need headless on a Macbook.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem when upgrading to Big Sur.  The solution is to uninstall OpenCV and reinstall it so that the binaries are built for Big Sur.  Simply doing `pip uninstall opencv-python` or `pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python` depending on what flavour you're using for OpenCV followed by a fresh install by `pip install opencv-python` or `pip install opencv-contrib-python` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade opencv-contrib-python to version 4.1.2.30.
Downgrade opencv-python to version 4.2.0.34.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MacOS Monterey.
I was able to solve it by switching from venv running python 3.9.2 to 3.10.2 release.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31190092)